# Injeção de Dependência em Projeto .Net Web API 2

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, injeção-de-dependência, asp.net-core, ioc

Estou envolvido num projeto que está desenvolvendo uma aplicação `.Net Web API 2 Fw 4.51` (com vistas à migração futura para `.Net Core`, o que é um 'agravante'), `Fluent NHibernate e PostgreSQL`, e estamos escolhendo um contêiner `IoC` que nos atenda de forma satisfatória.

Ficamos entre o `Unity, o Castle Windsor e o Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection` (por essa questão de migração futura para o .Net Core acabamos elencando a nova ferramenta da Microsoft na lista de possíveis candidatas). Como temos de ter a instanciação baseada nas `requests` ao serviço, gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês sobre qual dos dois é o mais adequado (ou, ainda, se vocês utilizariam outro contêiner).

Desde já, muito obrigado pela força!

Answer (score 1):

Eu escolheria Unity pelo simples fato que é o que estou mais acostumado e fornece suporte ao que eu preciso (Interceptors, Flexibilidade para definir escopo dos objetos etc) e também pq já encontrei gente usando para .NET core: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39173346/1384539